# SQL: Select id from table grouping by max year and name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data:

```
ID   Year    Name
1    2016    A
2    2015    A
3    2014    A
4    2014    B
5    2015    B
6    2010    C
7    2007    D
8    2008    D
9    2006    D
```

I need to query just the ID of the max date for each name group
Result: [1, 5, 6, 8 ]

which is really:

```
ID   Year    Name
1    2016    A
5    2015    B
6    2010    C
8    2008    D
```

I have the following, but don't know where to go from here

```
SELECT MAX(year) from table GROUP BY name
```

Ideally there should be no duplicate year and name groups, but if the there are duplicate records, then its possible. Since they would be duplicates, it would not matter which to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `name` then I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (name) t.*
from t
order by name, year desc;
```

If you have duplicates, then one solution is `rank()`:

```
select id, year, name
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by name order by year desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One could use row_number() analytic partitioned by name and ordered by year and ID desc to get the max ID for the max date.  You've not indicated if ties exist what you'd like to see...  but this would return one of them (the one with the highest ID.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ID
           , year
           , Name
           , row_number() over (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Year Desc, ID Desc) RN 
      FROM tbl) Z
WHERE RN = 1
```

An alternative way to accomplish this is to use your query as a inline view and simply join it back to the base set.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl A
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(year) mYear, name
            FROM tbl
            GROUP BY name) B
  on A.year = B.myear
 and A.Name = B.Name
```

Ties will be displayed.  So if you have a name with two records having a max year of 2016, then both records would be returned.

Comment: Let me test this, what is RN?

Comment: Do you have an extra ")" in your statement?

Comment: I am getting an error: subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: RN is row number is' a column alias. Yes there was an extra ) and I've added an alais to the subquery.